# "Beneath the branch of blue-glowing candles protruding from it glimmered the silver figure fifty-three"

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, sentence-structure, pronouns

> "Yeah," breathed Harry, looking up at the end of the closest row. **Beneath the branch of blue-glowing candles protruding from it glimmered the silver figure fifty-three**.
>
> <sub>Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix</sub>

I don't quite understand that sentence in bold above. I think the main verb is '**glimmered**', but I failed to identify the subject of it.

I'm not sure what **'it'** in **"protruding from it"** refers to.

And what does **'branch'** mean in this context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence can be re-written as follows, for better understanding:

> The silver figure fifty-three glimmered beneath the branch of blue-glowing candles protruding from it.

Subject: "The silver figure fifty-three" (note that here figure = number)
Verb: glimmered
Where did it glimmer? "beneath the branch of blue-glowing candles protruding from it"

---

> I'm not sure what 'it' in "protruding from it" refers to

My best guess is that  "it" refers to the "closest row", in the previous sentence.

---

> And what does 'branch' mean in this context?

Again, my best guess is that it refers to the (complex) candles holder, looking like trees. With branches. One branch for each candle.

[image: candle holder with branches]

---

Unfortunately, I failed to find an image on the net, showing the setup: the candles, the number 53... You may get lucky if you watch the movie - hopefully they have a depiction of this.